# Rails redirect to different port and protocol on same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to set up a route to redirect to my monit interface on a different port, but I'm
not sure how to do it. what I'd like is my https://domain.com:3000/monit
to redirect to http://domain.com:2812 .
I tried:

`get "/monit" => redirect("#{request.protocol}#{request.host}:2812")`

in my config.rb, but it doesn't seem to know about request, base_url or
anything else I can find.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes.rb file is loaded when your environment is created so it won't know 'request'.

You have to create a controller with a redirect_to to handle this.